# Dependency errors installing Proxmox on Debian 11

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies, proxmox

I am trying to install Proxmox on Debian 11, but running `apt install proxmox-ve postfix open-iscsi` fails:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 criu : Depends: python-future but it is not installable
        Depends: python-ipaddr but it is not installable
        Depends: python-protobuf but it is not installable
 libpve-u2f-server-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.28.1 but it is not installable
 librados2-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.28.1 but it is not installable
 proxmox-ve : Depends: pve-qemu-kvm but it is not installable
 pve-cluster : Depends: corosync (>= 2.3.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libqb0 (>= 0.17.1-1) but it is not installable
               Depends: perlapi-5.28.1 but it is not installable
               Depends: libcmap4 (>= 1.99.9) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libcpg4 (>= 2.3.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libquorum5 (>= 2.3.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
 qemu-server : Depends: pve-qemu-kvm (>= 3.0.1-62) but it is not installable
               Depends: libjson-c3 (>= 0.10) but it is not installable
 spiceterm : Depends: pve-qemu-kvm but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the repositories referenced in your setup are incorrect. To fix this, redo [the relevant step in the installation instructions](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Install_Proxmox_VE_on_Debian_11_Bullseye#Adapt_your_sources.list):

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.proxmox.com/debian/pve bullseye pve-no-subscription" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pve-install-repo.list
```

as root. You should also check that there are no other Proxmox references in files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` or in `/etc/apt/sources.list` itself.

Then, update with

```
apt update
```

(again, as root) and try the installation again.